# How to append string in a text using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'd like to append a specified string into a file, while this may sound like an easy task - and it surely is, I am struggling to make this working. Here is my script:

```
    TOMCAT_HOME=/home/osiris/Documents/work/sbr-brms/tomcat-script/apache-tomcat-8.0.22

    BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS="<role rolename=\"admin\"/>
    <role rolename=\"analyst\"/>
    <user username=\"bpmAdmin\" password=\"password1!\" roles=\"admin,analyst\"/>"

    #sed 's,<\/tomcat-users>,  $BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS   <\/tomcat-users>,' $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml

#sed "s,<\/tomcat-users>,  $BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS   <\/tomcat-users>," $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml

# awk -v r=$BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS '{ /<\/tomcat-users>/{print r}1}' $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.x
```

The first sed command does not get bash variable resolved, so it only prints out $BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS

The second sed command ends with:
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s' command

The third awk command ends with:
awk: cmd. line:1: rolename="admin"/>
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error

I believe this has something to do with the fact, that the string I want to write into the file includes " and . I haven't figure out a way how to escape it properly..

any advises welcome.

This is the original input http://pastebin.com/ZbTWmn7m
This should be the expected output http://pastebin.com/Gxtptuq3

Comment: What is the input and the expected output?

Comment: This is the input http://pastebin.com/ZbTWmn7m , and this should be the expected output http://pastebin.com/Gxtptuq3

Comment: To be perfectly clear I don't really care whether it is done by sed / awk or any other standard linux utility, just thought these two may be the most suitable candidates for such a simple task.

Comment: See this link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/how-to-insert-text-after-a-certain-string-in-a-file

Comment: @pasabaporaqui this does not really help me. sed  '/<\/tomcat-users>/i $BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS'  $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml ---> this does not resolve the bash variable $BUSINESS_CENTRAL_USERS and it just writes this as a plain text

Comment: add single quote to BUSSINES_CENTRAL_USERS itself and use double quote in sed command to allow replacement.

Comment: Does not help. it gives me following syntax error http://pastebin.com/HVKYZ6Bm I have posted before the input and expected output - are you able to achieve this with the commands you are suggesting? Can you give it a try before suggesting anything further?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will not waste your time anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to replace:

```
</tomcat-users>
```

with:

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="analyst"/>
  <user username="bpmAdmin" password="password1!" roles="admin,analyst"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

The sed command to replace a pattern and print all lines is:

```
sed s/pattern/replacement/
```

---

Escaping characters in sed can be tricky sometimes.

**pipes into sed (single quotes):**

```
cat tomcat-users.xml | sed 's/<\/tomcat-users>/\n<role rolename="admin"\/>\n  <role rolename="analyst"\/>\n  <user username="bpmAdmin" password="password1!" roles="admin,analyst"\/>\n<\/tomcat-users>/'
```

**uses sed directly (single quotes):**

```
sed -e 's/<\/tomcat-users>/\n<role rolename="admin"\/>\n  <role rolename="analyst"\/>\n  <user username="bpmAdmin" password="password1!" roles="admin,analyst"\/>\n<\/tomcat-users>/' tomcat-users.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Trevor! Just a small changes was needed so this could be parametrized with a variable - I have used double quotes instead of single, around that whole sed command and the variable is properly resolved. Initially, I wanted to let user to change the value of that variable, but seeing how complicated the syntax is, I am not sure if that's a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement before, ended up using a slightly different approach using the sed "c" command to replace a range of lines. I decided to rewrite the whole  section to make the script idempotent. I added also some validation to make sure I wasn't replacing commented lines. -i executes an in-place replacement.

```
sed -i '/^[ \t]*<tomcat-users>/,/^[ \t]*<\/tomcat-users>/c\<tomcat-users>\n<role rolename="admin"\/>\n<role rolename="analyst"\/>\n<user username="bpmAdmin" password="password1!" roles="admin,analyst"\/>\n<\/tomcat-users>' tomcat-users.xml
```